This isn't a typical convolution, what is it then?
In the numerous PlayStation emulators there are out there, this small piece of code is used to resample the input to feed to the reverb, which only works at 22050 Hz:
https://github.com/libretro-mirrors/mednafen-git/blob/master/src/psx/spu_reverb.inc#L69
// Zeroes optimized out; middle removed too(it's 16384)
static const int16 ResampTable[20] =
{
 -1, 2, -10, 35, -103, 266, -616, 1332, -2960, 10246, 10246, -2960, 1332, -616, 266, -103, 35, -10, 2, -1,
};

static INLINE int32 Reverb4422(const int16 *src)
{
 int32 out = 0; // 32-bits is adequate(it won't overflow)

 for(unsigned i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  out += ResampTable[i] * src[i * 2];

 // Middle non-zero
 out += 0x4000 * src[19];

 out >>= 15;

 clamp(&out, -32768, 32767);

 return(out);
}

If you look closely, the taps aren't applied to the samples in the usual way, rather, only one tap per sample.
Can you explain what's the logic behind this and why does it work?

I assume that it is a 2x downsampler (from 44100 to 22050) implemented using a halfband lowpass filter (~50% of the taps are zero).
The code appears to produce only a single output sample (must be called repeatedly with the *src pointer shifted appropriately each time). Thus it is not what I would think of as a "convolution" but rather a (specialized) inner-product
If you want to analyze the filter I think you can do this:
h = [-1, 0, 2, 0, -10, 0, 35, 0, -103, 0, 266, 0, -616, 0, 1332, 0, -2960, 0, 10246, 16384];
h = [h(1:end), h(end-1:-1:1)];
figure, 
freqz(h,1,1024,44100)



Would like to ask, 1. does such phase shift indicate a poor filter? 2. what did you use to generate these graphs, matlab? numpy? Thanks.

The filter is linear phase (symmetric) so the "steps" should be just (un-)wrapping snags. I used MATLAB.

That small but genius piece of code kept me busy for a while! And I've been able to produce the same graphs as yours using scipy. Thanks!
